# Can't add new owl file on apache jena

Tags: java, jena

In apache jena interface in my localhost, upload file option is not working. When I clik on this button nothing happens. With F12 I check the Network Tab (chrome) and I can see there the "server" is red and Error 403: Forbidden message. How I can fix it?

Comment: Which version are you running? What is teh setup? e.g. Is there a proxy? Have you used any of the Fuseki security features? The log file may have more information. 
A 403 response to an endpoint call can be for a number of reasons:

Answer (score 0):

First I used the version 3.17.0. Then I downloaded and set up the version 3.13.1.
In this version (3.13.1) there's not any problem with the server like 403:forbidden. My problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with 3.17.0 in Chrome. It works in Firefox though. Otherwise, download the 3.16.0 version, which works well in Chrome.